# Trigger send is not working for subscriber list?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I created smart capture based on Email Subscriber list (i.e list1) and Published same. Now I created trigger send by selecting list1 and simple template 
based email (no amp script inside), remaining required fields. Now I publish and ran the trigger definition. Now I fill the smart capture and submitted, Then data captured in list1 but trigger send not working for newly added data.

Comment: This isn't how triggered sends works. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_triggered_email_campaign_workflow.htm  you need to make an api call to send a triggered send

Comment: What is your actual question? What behavior do you observe?